# Can You Preserve Column Order When Pandas Dataframe.Combine Or DataFrame.Combine_First?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If you have 2 dataframes, represented as:

```
    A    F    Y
0   1    2    3
1   4    5    6
```

And

```
    B    C    T
0   7    8    9
1   10   11   12
```

When combining it becomes:

```
    A    B    C    F    T    Y
0   1    7    8    2    9    3
1   4    10   11   5    12   6
```

I would like it to become:

```
    A    F    Y    B    C    T
0   1    2    3    7    8    9
1   4    5    6    10   11   12
```

**How do I combine 1 data frame with another but keep the original column order?**

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`?

Comment: `df1.join(df2)`? assuming you want to combine on the index

Comment: What method are you using now to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1294]: new_df = df.join(df1)                                                                                                                                                                            

In [1295]: new_df                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1295]: 
   A  F  Y   B   C   T
0  1  2  3   7   8   9
1  4  5  6  10  11  12
```

OR you can also use `pd.merge`(not a very clean solution though)

```
In [1297]: df['tmp' ] =1                                                                                                                                                                                

In [1298]: df1['tmp'] = 1 

In [1309]: pd.merge(df, df1, on=['tmp'], left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('tmp', 1)                                                                                                                  
Out[1309]: 
   A  F  Y   B   C   T
0  1  2  3   7   8   9
1  4  5  6  10  11  12
```

Comment: This is what I needed, not Dataframe.combine. Thank you. Also, thanks to @You_Chris Who had mentioned this in the comments

Comment: It may also be worth nothing that df.join(df2, how='outer') allows you to preserve data if the indecies are different. I had to do that in the practical application of your answer.